# Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'members'

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot to ban all members in my server, but it doesn't work. I know I'm doing something wrong with ctx, but I don't know what. This is the code that doesn't work:

```
@client.command()
async def mpbga(guild):
    for member in guild.members:
        try:
            await member.ban(reason="vibe check", delete_message_days=0)
        except discord.Forbidden:
            pass
```

I get this error message:

```
Ignoring exception in command mpbga:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 79, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "death2.py", line 20, in mpbga
    for member in guild.members:
AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'members'
```

Can someone please help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The first argument passed to a command is always the [`Context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context). In this case it's being passed as the `guild` parameter.
You can use the [`Context.guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.guild) attribute for the guild the command was sent in.

See [the documentation for the commands extension](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html) for more information.